# Search filter no longer working when moved into ng-include (AngularJS)

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, data-binding, angularjs-filter

Early on in my project I wasn't able to isolate some of my views and had to develop them directly inside index.html. Specifically, my navigation menu.

Now I've been able to get `ng-include` to work and I would like to pull out my menu into nav.html. That's totally fine and still functions almost entirely as expected.

But I have a search bar in my menu that no longer functions. Initially, even though my nav menu was directly inside index.html, the contents it filtered was in an `ng-view`. Both the view I wanted to filter and the nav were under the same controller, though, and I have not changed the `ng-view` component.
But now that I've isolated the nav.html, the search filter no longer seems to be binding.

**index.html**:

```
...
<body>
    <div ng-include="'views/nav.html'"></div>
    <div ng-view></div>
    ...
</body>
...
```

**nav.html**:

```
<div class="nav">
    <div ng-controller="NavController">
        ...
        <div class="searchbar">
            <input type="text" name="input" value="Search" ng-model="search" /> 
<!--ng-model="search" is the binding component, as I understand-->
        </div> <!--end searchbar div-->
        ...
    </div> <!--end NavController div-->
</div> <!--end nav div-->
```

**table.html**: (the content to be filtered in `ng-view`)

```
<div ng-controller="NavController">
    <table>
        <tr class="title_bar">
            <td>Title</td>
            <td>A</td>
            <td>B</td>
        </tr>

        <tr ng-repeat="item in listOfItems | filter:search">
<!--table rows should be filtered by the search-->
            <td>{{item.title}}</td>
            <td>{{item.A}}</td>
            <td>{{item.B}}</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

I haven't changed table.html at all, nor have I changed nav.html. I merely isolated it into its own html file and `ng-include`'d it rather than had it there directly.

Any ideas? I would appreciate any help. Thank you!

Answer (score 7):

This may be a late answer, but it may help anyone who runs into this issue in the future:
I found out recently that ng-repeat's filter appears to be broken when the file containing the input field is included using ng-include. This is because ng-include creates a new (child) scope and you can use the $parent scope notation to resolve the issue:

So the input field in your nav.html should be modified to look like this:

```
        <input type="text" name="input" value="Search" ng-model="$parent.search.$" />
```

Comment: Glad I finally found this answer! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The nav.html and the table.html have the same controller NavController? If you split the views why don't you split the controllers?

I think if you split the controllers like you splitter the views everything will be working. Also if you use de ng-view you will use the routing so the controller will be binded two times to the table.html.

Comment: Originally they had different controllers, but I wanted the nav to be able to impact the table, and I was unable to do that with the data in different controllers. I have more filters connecting the table data with the nav than just the search, and I was unsure how to connect the two. (That's ultimately what I wanted to do, but couldn't figure out how, so I just combined them.)

Comment: You can use a rootscope variable that will contain the value of the search input that will be used in the filter of the table i will create a single example for you, can i mail it to you